# I have licence for WebSphere Application Server (Base package) can that be used to create a Cluster environment

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, horizontal-scaling

I have got WebSphere Application Server base version and I need to deploy application in horizontal cluster. Can that be achieved without Network Deployment version?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create and manage cluster on base version.

What you can do, is so called [Simple load balancing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/twsv_configsimplelb.html?lang=en). So you have 2 separate servers, where you have to manually, separately  deploy same application and configure IBM Http sever to do the load balancing among these 2 servers.

So you have a failover and load balancing, but without centralized management.